# jQuery UI datepicker: restrict last 5 days of each month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

My goal is to have the first 7 days of each month, and last 5 days of each month disabled in jQuery UI datepicker.  I see that there are ways to set maxDate and minDate, however that is specified from the current date.

**Problem**:
I managed to get the first 7 days disabled, however the last 5 days of each month vary since some end with 28 days or 31 etc.

**My code**:

```
$('input, .ui-datepicker').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if (date.getDate() <= 7) {
          return [false, ''];
        }
        return [true, ''];
      }
    });
```

Is there a way to accomplish `disabling the last 3 or 5 days of each month` without hardcoding dates from months in an array?

If this is already answered please direct me to the answered question, I haven't found it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the last day of the month in javascript Date library

```
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {day:'numeric'});
```

Use that as a constraint for an if statement.